# Joint Pdf Question

Tags: probability

Suppose $X$, $Y$ are independent and I know that the joint pdf of $X$ and $Y$ is $f_{X, Y}(t_1, t_2) = A(t_1)B(t_2)$ where $A(t_1)$ is the pdf of $X$ and $B(t_2)$ is the pdf of $Y$? Then what is $f_{X^2, Y}(t_1, t_2)?$ Is it  $A(t_1)^2B(t_2)$ or $C(t_1)B(t_2)$ where $C$ is the pdf of $X^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the second. The random variables $X^2$ and $Y$ are independent, so the joint pdf of $X^2$ and $Y$ is the product of the pdf's of $X^2$ and $Y$.

Note that the pdf of $X^2$ is almost never the square of the pdf of $X$.

Comment: Sorry but how does $X$ and $Y$ independent $\implies$ $X^2$ and $Y$ are independent?

Comment: In general, if $X$ and $Y$ are independent, so are $f(X)$ and $g(Y)$.

Comment: Oh, this is measure theoretic where $f$ and $g$ have to be Borel measurable.

Comment: I did not know at what level the question was at, if we are talking about density functions then the level is fairly elementary. In any case, the function $f(t)=t^2$ is not problematic in any setting.

Comment: No you are right, the original question is elementary and I just wanted to confirm. The other comment was just for fun, as I self-studied a little measure theory on my own.